# WriteProcessMemory no error and it don't writes to correct address

Tags: c++

First i read the correct Value from the Address: This part works fine.

```
 ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)(baseAddr + staticOffset), &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
 value += 0x174;
 ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
 value += 0x4;
 ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
 value += 0xc;
 ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
 value += 0x130;
 ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
```

You see this is a lvl 4 pointer and the Value have the correct information. Now i have think, hey let's decrease that Value by 1 and Write the result back in this address.

```
  newValue = value - 1; //new value is a DWORD
  std::cout << "WriteValue: " << newValue << std::endl;
            if (!WriteProcessMemory(phandle, &value, &newValue, sizeof(DWORD), NULL))
            {
                std::cout << "Oh write error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }

            ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
            std::cout << "After write Value: " << value << std::endl;
```

Now, no error and the address value don't change. I don't have much experience with Write Memory and hope you can help me.

**Important:** I only use this for my own processes. I am currently learning reverse enginnering.

I also tried:

```
WriteProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID)value, &newValue, sizeof(DWORD), NULL)
```

> ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS
>
> ```
> 487 (0x1E7)
>
> Attempt to access invalid address.
> ```

Comment: Do distinguish between address and value in the code.  Using &value is not a correct address, delete &.

Comment: i mean to value without & is the correct adress. i used on ReadProcessMemory alot of times. So im rly out of ideas why WriteProcessMemory want work with this. Thanks for help.

Comment: I have found the error, I have overwritten the value  :/ Ty @Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` Gets the address of the variable that comes after it. Ex. `&value`. So what you're trying to do is write to the address of the variable `value` and since `value` is contained in the address space of your own process that means the address passed by `&value` may or may not be valid in the remote process.

You don't need to store the final `ReadProcessMemory` in `value`. At the moment that last `ReadProcessMemory` is storing the actual value you want and not the address of the value. Instead have `value` be a pointer to the variable you're trying to access in the remote process and create a new variable to hold the value you're trying to access.

And since you put `sizeof(DWORD)` as a parameter in both write and read I'm gonna assume the type of the value you want is `DWORD` as well.

As such:

```
ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)(baseAddr + staticOffset), &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
 value += 0x174;
 ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
 value += 0x4;
 ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
 value += 0xc;
 ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
 value += 0x130;
 DWORD dwValue = 0;
 ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &nValue, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
```

Now `value` holds the address of the variable and `dwValue` contains the value of that variable.

However `newValue = value - 1` needs to now be `newValue = dwValue - 1`.

And `ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &value, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead)` needs to become `ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &dwValue, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead)`. Likewise `std::cout << "After write Value: " << value << std::endl;` needs to become `std::cout << "After write Value: " << dwValue << std::endl;`.

Result:

```
newValue = dwValue - 1; //new value is a DWORD
  std::cout << "WriteValue: " << newValue << std::endl;
            if (!WriteProcessMemory(phandle, &value, newValue, sizeof(DWORD), NULL))
            {
                std::cout << "Oh write error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            }

            ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPCVOID)value, &dwValue, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
            std::cout << "After write Value: " << dwValue << std::endl;
```

I highly encourage you to learn more about virtual memory, pointers, etc. There's a plethora of tutorials online. Might take a while to get good but you'll get it eventually. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks for your very nice answer. The error I have already determined. :) I've already seen many tutorials but must say that the application of pointer has not quite understood. Only now I am aware of how pointers work. I will of course try to learn more, everything needs its time. I wish you a nice tomorrow.

Comment: @Staubi Glad that you resolved the issue. I imagine you are making a game hack huh? If so I suggest your next step to be making a dll and learning about dll injection. It's a lot easier to access memory from an injected dll since you have all rights to the remote process's memory. Then slow API calls can just become basic pointer arithmetic and as easy as assigning a variable a value instead of using `WriteProcessMemory`. Either way good luck! I wish you well! :)

Comment: (1) Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am currently trying to program a bot in my own little game. I'm doing this because I want to understand what an attacker has to do to get the correct information. The goal would be to make the attacker as difficult as possible. Unfortunately, I currently have almost no DLL knowledge, only I know that a DLL is a library which one can use to call functions. I am currently unclear what advantages are offered by an injecten. "Oh no, dont enough space goto 2"

Comment: (2) The addresses must be determined exactly the same, whether the call happens by a DLL or directly over a seperates program, does not seem to make a big difference for me. Only I have thought that a DLL is faster detected, because you are in a strange process. As an example could be determined which DLL's currently loaded. If one finds here a DLL which is not part of the system is the fraud / hack already ends.

Comment: @Staubi You are correct, a Dll is most commonly used for calling functions from it. Like a toolbox you pull tools out of. Injecting a Dll has a good amount of advantages. You have full access to the remote process because once your Dll is injected it's a part of that remote process. Memory hacks in which you freeze values (repeatedly write the same value to them) are much faster in an injected Dll. Compare the speed of an API call (`WriteProcessMemory`) to regular assignment of a variable (`nValue = x`). When you get into memory scanning/AOB scanning Dll injection is much more efficient than..

Comment: @Staubi ..costly API calls to a remote process. Especially if you ever want to hack a 64-bit game. And most anti-cheat like VAC which steam uses only blacklists Dll's, compares Dll's against a list of known Dll's used for cheating. Most will not block Dll's they don't recognize because a lot of screen capturing software injects Dll's into the window they record. There are a number of advantages to Dll injection and is currently what most hacks rely on because game trainers/external hacks (`Read/WriteProcessMemory`) get detected.

Comment: But it's up to you whether or not you think it's worth the time to learn. It's quite interesting in my opinion and if you really want to avoid people cheating in your game then I highly suggest you learn about Dll injection and how to prevent people from cheating that way. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: Maybe I understand something wrong. Why should a DLL be faster? Do not have to use a DLL just like Write / Read to change things? If not, I do not understand how to get the data.

Can you explain to me why Write / Read is detected? To do this, you would have to monitor all other programs on the computer and guess whether an external program is manipulated. And that would be illegal. Thanks you

Comment: @Staubi When a Dll is injected into a process it gains access to that processes virtual memory as if it were it's own. So just like how if you made your own program you would read from an address simply by explicitly assigning a pointer the address you want you can do that in an injected Dll. i.e. `int* pInt = (int*)0xDAA588`. And as such you can access and change variables without API calls. i.e. `*pInt = 100`. It's faster because `*pInt = 100` more or less compiles to `mov eax, 100` in assembly. However `WriteProcessMemory` takes many more instructions to do the same task...

Comment: ..making it much slower. And since API functions like `WriteProcessMemory` can be hooked they can be detected by anti-cheat when they are called. You can monitor API calls and hook functions using different publicly available libraries like MHook, detours, etc. However since `*pInt = 100` doesn't use any API calls it can't be hooked and be detected that way.

Comment: (1) Thanks for the great description. Ok that make much more sense now. @Assambly I've been doing some tutorials and must say o my god.

As an example I have the address selected by the HP of the player. After that, I looked at the memory view in Cheat Engine once: `mov [eax + 04], edi`.

From some tutorials I know now the eax and edi registers, which represent a kind of memory.
I assume the eax + 04 the actual hp represents. eax = register, 04 offset. Is this true? Gotto 2

Comment: (2) I am a bit confused since I have actually expected a dec command. This would make sense in my opinion. In addition, I would very wonder what the edi exactly does. Can you enlighten me?
I thank you very much for your time and patience!

Comment: Oh, mistake from my site. eax+04 = register adress, edi = value. Hope this is true :P So a bether question is maybe: How i know or become the edi value?

Comment: @Staubi In C++ the `eax` register very commonly is used for return values. If you look at the decompilation of a C++ program it's likely you'll see heavy use of `eax`. `mov [eax + 04], edi` Very important to note that in CheatEngine all offsets are usually represented as a hexadecimal. 0x04 is still 4 in decimal but 0x64 is NOT 64 in decimal. It's 100, keep this in mind while you deal with offsets and stuff and I'm sure you're already aware. In assembly the result of the operation is always stored in the left operand. This means when `mov` copies `edi` it's going to store it in `[eax +04]` ...

Comment: The brackets `[]` mean that operand is an address and not an immediate value. So lets say `eax = 0x000D8864`, `[eax + 04]` points to the address `0x000D8868`. And lets say `edi = 0x64`, that means `mov [eax + 04], edi` copies `0x64`/`100` into the address `0x000D8868`. It moves the actual value of `edi` and not what it would point to if it were an address. So instead of trying to copy memory from address `0x64` it copies `0x64` itself because it's an immediate value because it doesn't have brackets around it.

Comment: @Staubi Oh about what `edi` does, sorry forgot :P. `edi` Is most commonly used for string operations because it's used for copying arrays. That's what it's main purpose is. Is it always used that way? No. And also about expecting a `dec`. Many new games I've seen have multiple addresses to store copies of important values like health, ammo, etc. So I figure they subtract it from the copies then copy (`mov`) that value into it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your descritions are beateful. I have read some stuff here: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html . If im understand that +- then i can simply do `mov edi, (BYTE) 5` befor the example comming. And the adress: `0x000D8868` have now the value 5 ? :P

Comment: Or Simply replace `edi` with 0x64. Then never change the value 100 in adress or? `mov [eax + 04], 0x64`. I wish you happy night

Comment: You're correct, it would result in the example address being equal to 5 after the operation. And yes, you can replace `edi` with `0x64`. If you had an instruction you knew wrote to health, instead of having to get a pointer path and etc you could just get the address of the instruction. Replace the register with 0x64 and it'll write the value for you. Instructions usually are `module+offset`. So you can call `GetModuleHandle` then add an offset, write 0x64 over the register and that's it. However, that would likely change the length of the instruction in bytes because a constant takes more....

Comment: ...bytes to represent than a register does. Which means the opcodes for the next instruction would get overwritten, undefined behavior and the game crashes. But you could instead replace it with a `jmp` to memory you allocated to contain the modified `mov` then have it `jmp` back to the next instruction originally after the `mov`. Not as complicated as it sounds once you better understand assembly.

Comment: Thank you. I have write small c++ program to test some of that learning stuff with cheat engine. Now the program crash :P^^ Maybe you have discord or something? My Reputation is not enough to chat, if u want. I dont see any pm method :/ Thank you again for your time. More poeple like you and the world would be a better. :)

Comment: The error is fixxed, i think know now how assambly works+-. If you still have time, I would still have some questions to the topic pointer. I wish you a pleasant day

Comment: Of course, glad to help! :) I don't have discord but I do have Skype. You can add me on there: `edward.severinsen`. If you don't have a Skype let me know and I'm sure we can work something out.

Answer (score 0):

The last call of ReadProcessMemory overwritten the correct address.

```
ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (LPVOID)value, &newDWORD, sizeof(DWORD), &numBytesRead);
```

Now i change the output variable and the WriteProcessMemory function works fine.